# Remove Duplicates if multiple criteria are met

Tags: excel, vba, database, if-statement

I have a database that contains multiple lines of info. I need a VBA code that will delete duplicate rows if data in columns 5, 10, 11 and 12 all match. Only once all all 4 columns data matches will the row then be deleted. Cant use remove duplicates manually as data will be pasted in and out of this worksheet constantly. I have tried but cannot get my brain around it so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried remove duplicate VBA code with If statements but cant get it to work correctly.

Comment: If you have Power Query, it will handle this with ease.  Just use a "Group" command and group by the 4 fields you want to evaluate and return the MIN of each column.

Answer (score 0):

My first idea: Create a helper column with the following formula

```
    =COUNTIFS($E$2:$E2,E2,$J$2:$J2,J2,$K$2:$K2,K2,$L$2:$L2,L2)>1
```

(assuming that you have a header column and your data starts at row 2)
Copy the formula down so that it's present for all rows.

To ensure that the formula will be added automatically, it may be a good idea to convert your data to a table. Also, you should set a protection to the formula column so that the user cannot overwrite it accidentally.

Now you can set a filter to that column and delete all rows where the value is `TRUE` (be careful, I think you should create a backup before you do so the first time).

Comment: Issue with this and I did forget to mention, the database is used as part of a pivot table to analyse info against other documents.

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming data table starts from cell A1 and has header row
- Use `RemoveDuplicates` to remove duplicated rows

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.RemoveDuplicates method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144243)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        If .Columns.Count > 11 Then
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(5, 10, 11, 12), Header:=xlYes
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: I've tried this, specifying the actual sheet. Runs but doesn't actually do anything

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
 Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).